# How to find the users that logged on the current day and mention the time they logged?

Tags: bash

How to find the users that logged on the current day and mention the
time they logged on and how long they were on the system. Put it in columnar format and post it as HTML format?

Comment: This might help with Linux: `man last`

Comment: 1. get logon time of users. 2. output as columns in HTML. That's two different problems.